# Custom load class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to make custom load class for codeigniter. For my theme switcher system I am making.

I would like to be able to do some thing like this. I am stuck on this issue?

**$this->load->controller('folder/file');**

**$this->load->controller('folder/folder/file');**

**"controller"** is a custom function.

So can do this **$data['name] = $this->load->controller('folder/file');**

It just would make my life a lot easy if I could do it that way.

I am trying to make my own version of an min **hmvc** system. I know they always ask why do you need it. Always have to keep explaining it. Lots of people are after this way.

Comment: So you want to load a controller inside an other controller ?

Comment: Yes I know it can be done. Similar to HMVC but trying to make my own version so can edit that way. I have done most of the work just stuck on this. It can be done with base controller I know that be that's a extra file I do not need. I am doing this a work for free so its open source.

Comment: @Chen-TsuLin Lin Can you give me demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter manage it's class, helper, view, model, database.. loading in

`system/core/Loader.php`

It's why you can use

```
$this->load->view();
$this->load->database();
$this->load->model();
$this->load->database();
```

So, you can extends CI_Loader in

`application/core/MY_Loader.php`

add `controller` function and whatever you want

I found a demo in this blog post:
http://www.techsirius.com/2013/01/load-controller-within-another.html

**Edit:**

If you want to apply to other folder like subfolder, you can add some logic to `$file_name`

```
$file_path = APPPATH.'controllers/'.$file_name.'.php';
```

Comment: Just have to work out now how to make it pick up sub directory just only picks up one level.

Comment: It does not load $this->load->controller('header'); only loads in the function construct function __construct() $this->load->controller('header'); in the public function index $this->header->index(); i need the function to load like this $this->load->controller('header');

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to load a controller from an other controller.

You should use Helpers instead :)

http://www.codeigniter.fr/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: so helper to load $data['name] = $this->load->helper(folder/folder/file); Not sure how though. I looked into to it week ago not yet understand that part

Comment: I've never used helpers for the moment ...
I only see things about it so i can't help you more sorry.

But i understood that an helper is just a common function that you can use in many controllers ;)